# How to do encryption with any key

Tags: c#, encryption

I am implementing encryption with Rijndael symmetric algorithm. This is working, but I want to change this to work wirh any key. I do not want to generate key, I want to allow user to pick his own key, like his pasword for encryption.

```
RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
myRijndael.GenerateKey();
myRijndael.GenerateIV();

var encryptor = new RijndaelManagedEncryption();

var encrypted = encryptor.EncryptSettingValue(myRijndael.Key, "Encrypt this", myRijndael.IV);
```

For example like this

```
RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
myRijndael.GenerateIV();
var key = Convert.FromBase64String("pasword")
var encryptor = new RijndaelManagedEncryption();

var encrypted = encryptor.EncryptSettingValue(key , "Encrypt this", myRijndael.IV);
```

But if I do this I will get Exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

If you want see algorithm this is link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, string "password" is not a valid `Base64` string, so you can't convert from it like you want.

And more, you should not get a key for encryption "straightforward" from some string just because it will not generate well-randomized key.

Use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instead something like:

```
var password = "pasword";
var salt = new byte[] { 0xe3, 0x5c, 0x51, 0x6a, 0x13, 0x55, 0x46, 0xf8, 0x75, 0xba, 0x54, 0xc3, 0x42, 0x5b, 0x70, 0xac };
var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt).GetBytes(32);
```

Here `salt` is some random array of bytes, doesn't matter what it actually will be. It just needed to bring more randomness into key generation and can be any (but the same all the time to ensure you're generating identical keys from identical passwords).

Comment: Thanks. And how to go back? How to get password from key?

Comment: Why do you need get password from key? Typical use case: user provides password, you're generating the key and encrypting/decrypting using that key. Reverseal key -> password is not needed at all, and moreover, it is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: @merso0027 If you have arbitrary length passphrases, how do you expect to get a passphrase out of a fixed length key? It's simply not feasible for arbitrary passphrases.

Comment: Problem with this is that every time I call Rfc2898DeriveBytes I will get diferent value for same password. I want allow user to get crypted data, and every time he type password data is encrypted. VI is hardcoded (for example). If user type password, password is converted to key with Rfc2898DeriveBytes, how to get same key next time he type same password.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same `salt` each time you're generating key from password? If not - you should use the same salt every time, just hardcode it, and then you will get the same key from the same password. Run the code snippet I've provided several times and you will see - each time you're getting the same key because password and salt are the same.